# Не удается найти сеттер для атрибута, после того как класс был переписан на Kotlin

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-data-binding

я изучаю MVVM, и сказу хотел его использовать вместе с Kotlin, но оказалось это довольно сложно, не смотря на то, что в учебнике был MVVM описан на языке Kotlin.

Я сейчас выложу 3 класса, всё эти классы были взяты в качестве примера из учебника, которые были немного модифицированные. И прошу вас обратить ваше внимание на класс `Navigations.java`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var array : ArrayList<Navigations> = ArrayList()

    private lateinit var recycler : RecyclerView
    private lateinit var adapter : NavagationsSceneCustomAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recycler = findViewById(R.id.rv)

        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recycler.adapter = NavagationsSceneCustomAdapter(array)

        addDummyData()

    }

    private fun addDummyData() {

        val user0 = Navigations("Igor Vad", "http://risovach.ru/upload/2013/09/mem/lemur_28882510_big_.jpeg")
        array.add(user0)

        val user1 = Navigations("Thor", "http://memesmix.net/media/created/07fvm0.jpg")
        array.add(user1)

        val user2 = Navigations("Igor Vad", "http://pristor.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Картинки-с-приколами-и-надписями-смешными-смотреть-бесплатно-1.jpg")
        array.add(user2)

        val user3 = Navigations("Booger", "http://www.reactiongifs.com/r/i-guess.gif")
        array.add(user3)

        recycler.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        Log.d("TAG", array.size.toString())
    }
}
```

Второй класс реализует adapter для recyclerview

```
class NavagationsSceneCustomAdapter(private val arrays : List<Navigations>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<NavagationsSceneCustomAdapter.NavagationsSceneView>() {

    private var layoutInflater : LayoutInflater? = null;

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NavagationsSceneView {

        if(layoutInflater == null){
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        }

        val newsBinding = NewsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater!!, parent, false)

        return NavagationsSceneView(newsBinding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NavagationsSceneView, position: Int) {
        Log.d("TAG", arrays.size.toString() + " adapter")
        holder.bind(arrays[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = arrays.size



    class NavagationsSceneView(val newsBinding: NewsBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(newsBinding.root) {

        fun bind(navigationsSceneMVVM: Navigations){
            newsBinding.view = navigationsSceneMVVM
        }

        fun getNewsBindings() : NewsBinding = newsBinding

    }
}
```

Это последний класс который работает с данными, и он же самый проблемный. Сейчас я опубликую реализацию на Java, следующий будет на Kotlin, он будет иметь другое имя и другие имена полей, не обращайте серьезное внимание на это.

```
public class Navigations implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String title, urls;

    public Navigations(String titleNavigation, String urls){
        this.title = titleNavigation;
        this.urls = urls;
    }

    public String getUrls() {
        return urls;
    }

    public void setUrls(String urls) {
        this.urls = urls;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @BindingAdapter({"app:urls"})
    public static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String url){
        Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(url).into(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new Toast(v.getContext()).makeText(v.getContext(), title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Ранее я использовал класс который был написан на Kotlin.

```
data class NavagationsSceneMVVM(var title : String, val urls2 : String) : View.OnClickListener{
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        Log.d("TAG 1 ", urls2)
        Toast.makeText(p0?.getContext(), title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }


    @BindingAdapter("app:urls") // Здесь вся проблема и начинается.
    fun loadImage(view: ImageView, url: String) {
        Glide.with(view.context).load(url).into(view)
    }

}
```

Используя `NavagationsSceneMVVM.kt` ***я получаю ошибку***.

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:imageUrl' with parameter type java.lang.String on android.widget.ImageView.
```

Я не знаю как этот сеттер указать в Kotlin, чтобы исчезла эта ошибка.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="ua.com.im_a_welder.imawelder.viewmodel.DataItemViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.images}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:text="@{viewModel.title}"
            tools:text="Item Title" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Читать: https://proandroiddev.com/custom-attributes-using-bindingadapters-in-kotlin-971ef8fcc259

Comment: Статический `loadImage(...)` в Java не то же самое что у вас в Kotlin получилось.

Comment: Спасибо, быстро прикрутить к проекту подход автора не удалось. Видимо автор использует другой подход реализации mvvm, я проверил, он сложный для меня, поэтому мне будет нужно время чтобы понять как работает его код.

Comment: Вы можете оформить ответ, чтобы если что, я его смог принять в будущем.